# Re-check authorized user (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, razor-pages

I’m new in asp.net core razor pages.

After several days I could implement auhtentication process using my own data base and code.

My login page checks user/password and also if a user is active (a flag in my table).

Let suppose the administrator changes an auhorized user (he is using the system), setting this user to inactive, or even change roles auhtorized. How can I re-check auhorization in the pipeline?

My code

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
....
      services.AddScoped<IAuthenticateService, AuthenticateService>();

      services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddCookie(options =>
         {
           options.LoginPath = "/Login";
           options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
           options.AccessDeniedPath = "/NotAcess";
         });
......

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
....
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

    // In AuthenticateService (called by login page after checking user existence and password)
    private async Task AuthenticateExecAsync(User user, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
      if (user.Status != User.Status_Active)
        throw new Exception("User inactive");

      var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email));
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.Name));
      List<string> roles = new List<string>();
      foreach (var item in user.userRoles)
        roles.Add(item.Role.RoleId);
      foreach (var role in roles)
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
      var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
      await httpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in this forum:

https://forums.asp.net/p/2167309/6306278.aspx?p=True&t=637261738568923978

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you inject IAuthenticationService into the class where you need to authenticate?

Comment: The problem is that I need in all the classes. All the transactions are protected by authorization, it is a system whith several roles and users could be fired any time.